# display an image / what does asset do?

Tags: php, symfony

I try to display an image which is in **web/uploads/img**

this image has the following name: **Screenshot_2014-12-24-23-01-17.png**

1/ when doing this, it **works** perfectly:

```
 <img src="{{ asset('uploads/img/Screenshot_2014-12-24-23-01-17.png') }}" />
```

2/ when doing the following (the path of the image is in a variable)  **nothing is displayed** :

```
 <img src="{{ asset(array_image_WebPath[t]) }}" />
```

( with t = 1 and array_image_WebPath[1] = uploads/img/Screenshot_2014-12-24-23-01-17.png)

The fact is that I need to store my webpath of my images in an array. So what is the proper way of doing it?

---

**EDIT:** I tried with objects directly doing the following: {% for image in liste_images %} '<'img src="{{ asset(image.webpath)}}"/> {% endfor ‰} AND IT WORKS **but I need to use my array** to get the right image at the right place.

Comment: are you sure array_image_WebPath[1] = uploads/img/Screenshot_2014-12-24-23-01-17.png ?

Comment: well when I do {{ array_image_WebPath[1] }} in twig, i got uploads/img/Screenshot_2014-12-24-23-01-17.png displayed

Answer (score 1):

Go with a [`for...in`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html):

```
{% for image in array_image_WebPath %}
  <img src="{{ asset(image) }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

And access the loop index with either `loop.index` or `loop.index0` [respectively 1 and 0 based].